# Node.js and fragmentation

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, garbage-collection, v8

**Background**: I came from Microsoft world, in which I used to have websites stored on IIS. Experience taught me to recycle my application pool once a day in order to eliminate weird problems due to fragmentation. Recycling the app pool basically means to restart your application without restarting the entire IIS. I also watched a lecture that explained how Microsoft had reduced the fragmentation  a lot in .Net 4.5.

Now, I'm deploying a Node.js application to production environment and I have to make sure that it works flawlessly all the time. I originally thought to make my app restarted once a day. Then I did some research in order to find some clues about fragmentation problems in Node.js. The only thing I've found is a scrap of paragraph from [an article describing GC in V8](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-performance-garbage-collection/):

> To ensure fast object allocation, short garbage collection pauses, and
>   the “no memory fragmentation V8” employs a stop-the-world,
>   generational, accurate, garbage collector.

This statement is really not enough for me to give up building a restart mechanism for my app, but on the other hand I don't want to do some work if there is no problem.

So my quesion is:

Should or shouldn't I restart my app every now and then in order to prevent fragmentation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementing a server restart before you know that memory consumption is indeed a problem is a premature optimization. As such, I don't think you should do it until you actually find that it is a problem. You will likely find more important issues to optimize for as opposed to memory consumption.

**To figure out if you need a server restart, I recommend doing the following:**

1. Set up some monitoring tools like https://newrelic.com/ that let's your monitor your performance.
2. Monitor your memory continuously. Try to see if there is steady   increase in the amount of memory consumed, or if it levels off.
3. Decide upon an acceptable threshold before you need to act. For example once your app consumes 60% of system memory you need to start thinking about a server restart and decide upon the restart interval.
4. Decide if you are ok with having "downtime" while restarting the sever or not. If you don't want downtime, you may need to build a proxy layer to direct traffic.

In general, I'd recommend server restarts for all dynamic, garbage collected languages. This is fairly common in those types of large applications. It is almost inevitable that a small mistake somewhere in your code base, or one of the libraries you depend on will leak memory. Even if you fix one leak, you'll get another one eventually. This may frustrate your team, which will basically lead to a server restart policy, and a definition of what is acceptable in regards to memory consumption for your application.

Comment: to be clear, you recommend server restarts WITH monitoring, right? I have bad experiences with higher-ups restarting apps that have issues without any kind of info of why they have these issues so it stays a guessing game.

Comment: @CorvusCrypto I recommend monitoring first. And then deciding if a server restart is necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborated answer. I have two questions: 1. How can memory leaks happen in a managed code language? Afaik a memory leak occurs when you don't release a memory allocation that you don't use anymore; but in a managed code app every object you don't have a reference to anymore gets released by the GC. (2nd question is in the next comment).

Comment: 2. In contrast to releasing unused objects and that way preventing memory leaks, managed code languages (like C# which I'm coming from) are less successful in preventing fragmentation. I have read that you cannot monitor fragmentation because it's not considered as memory your program consumes, so the memory use appears deceptively low, am I wrong?

Comment: @Alon For #1) One example where this happens and its hard to de-allocate memory is event handlers. If you continually build up event handlers and never remove them you'll get a memory leak. Especially when there 2 way bindings all over your application. On the serverside this can happen to depending on your architecture. I think it may also be possible to allocate too many promises and just continually hang on to them. It is a different class of memory management problem for sure, but there are still leaks. In regards to #2) I'm not hearing much about memory fragmentation for node.

Comment: Continuing #2) I believe v8 has a "mark-compact" strategy, which takes care of memory fragmentation issues.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Parris. You should probably figure out whether you actually need have a restart policy first. I would suggest using pm2 [docs here](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/). Even if you don't want to sign up for keymetrics, its a pretty good little process manager and real quick to set up. You can get a report of memory usage from command line. Looks something like this.

[image: pm2 output]

Also, if you start in cluster mode like above, you can call `pm2 restart my_app` and the first one will probably be up again before the last one is taken offline (this is an added benefit, the real reason for having 8 processes is to utilize all 8 cores). If you are adamant about downtime, you could restart them 1 by 1 acording to id.

Comment: With PM2 you can also get a "guaranteed" no downtime reload with `pm2 reload my_app` [docs here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/#reload).

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Parris this seems like a premature optimization. Also, restarting is not a solution to the underlying problem, it's a treatment for the symptoms.

If memory errors are a prevalent issue for your node application then I think that some thought as to why this fragmentation occurs in your program in the first place could be a valuable effort. Understanding why memory errors occur after a program has been running for a long period of time, and refactoring the architecture of your program to solve the root of the problem, is a better solution in my eyes than just addressing the symptoms.

I believe two things will benefit you.

1. [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object) will help a lot, they are a lot more predictable than using mutable objects, and will not be affected by the length of time the project has been live. Also, since immutable objects are read only blocks of memory they are faster than mutable objects which the server has to spend resources deciding whether to read, or write on the memory block which stores the object. I currently use the library called [IMMUTABLE](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and it works well for me. There are other one's as well like [Deep Freeze](https://github.com/substack/deep-freeze), however, I have never used it.
2. Make sure to manage your application's processes correctly, memory leaks are the second big contributor to this problem that I have experienced. Again, this is solved by thinking about how your application is structured, and how user events are handled, making sure once a process is not being used by the client that it is properly removed from the `heap`, if it is not then the `heap` keeps growing until all memory is consumed causing the application to crash(refer to the below graphic to see V8's memory Scheme, and where the `heap` is). Node is a C++ program, and it's controlled by Google's V8 and Javascript.

[image: V8 memory Scheme]

You can use Node.js's `process.memoryUsage()` to monitor memory usage. When you identify how to manage your heap V8 offers two solutions, one is Scavenge which is very quick, but incomplete. The other is Mark-Sweep which is slow and frees up all non-referenced memory.

Refer to [this](http://jayconrod.com/posts/55/a-tour-of-v8-garbage-collection) blog post for more info on how to manage your heap and manage your memory on V8 which runs Node.js

So the responsible approach to your implementation is to keep a close eye on open processes, a deep understanding of the `heap`, and how to free non-referenced memory blocks. Creating your project with this in mind also makes the project a lot more scaleable as well.

Comment: I think the point is that all dynamic languages will eventually leak.